# What's the best approach to store data URL(base64) in mvc project?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I save the images as dataurl onto database (stored as string in the column), but this way is not efficient way to get/store datas. After googled about that, I found out some solutions. Likewise, split the data url on the comma and base64 decoded data.Then write binary data to a file, but I don't have any idea how to save the data to a file.

```
**Base64**  ==>  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhyAD3APcAAAAAAAoKChISEhsbGyAcHSMjIyomJysrKzMvMDMzMzk2Nzw8PEJCQklFRkpHSExMTFJSUltbW2NjY2hmZmpnaGtra3BtbXNzc3x8fOJHIOJLJeNOKOVRJuhWJ+lZJ+NQK+xdKONVMuRYNeRdOu5iJe5iKPBlKfBoLeV
```

Another solution is using ajax, which I didn't understand the way how to get data url from stored images in part of this code:

```
stage1.toDataURL({
    callback: function(dataUrl) {
        dataUrl = dataUrl.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../../Home/UploadImage",
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + dataUrl + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
               // alert('Image saved successfully !');
                window.location("Home/ExportPng");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this code how I use dataurl in aspx file and angularjs.

```
var c = document.getElementById(myCanvasDoc);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById(imagedoc);
var imgwidth = img.offsetWidth;
var imgheight = img.offsetHeight;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgwidth, imgheight);
$scope.image.src= c.toDataURL(); 



<img data-ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="500" height="300" />
<img id="imagedoc" data-flow-img="$flow.files[0]" width="500" height="300" />     
<canvas id="myCanvasDoc" width="500" height="300" />
```

Hopefully, I could explain my problem and what I need. Please help me find the solution if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say that a database isn't an efficient way to get/store data, however i'll try my best to give you some advice.

If you're create a front end only using AngularJS with no back end I recommend you use localstorage, preferably one with a cookie fallback, i'd recommend [Angular Local Storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

If you have a back end, I recommend you use a database of some description, be it [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/about/) or something more document oriented like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/) I notice in the tags it does say you're using ASP.Net so i'd recommend taking a look at [this detailed tutorial on building a RESTful API in ASP.Net](http://bitoftech.net/2013/11/25/detailed-tutorial-building-asp-net-web-api-restful-service/).

Hope this helped and if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: First, thank you for answer. Sorry for unclear question. Please let me explain more.

I mean that when convert images to dataurl, its size is around 10.000-12.000 characters.That's a huge size while trying to store the data into database colomn(btw I use MsSQL database). So, that causes problems(pages are running slow when download or upload images or etc.) when get datas from database. That's why I want to learn what's the best approach to store dataurl.